# ECB: truncate lines in symbol definition buffer

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-ecb

Emacs ECB 2.40 has a layout called `left-symboldef`, it has the `*ECB Symboldefinition*` buffer, and I want to set

```
(setq truncate-lines nil)
```

there. I browsed the customized group:

```
M-x customize-group ecb-symboldef
```

It doesn't have such an option. But it mentions the hook. So I tried:

```
(add-hook 'ecb-symboldef-buffer-sync (lambda ()
                                   (setq truncate-lines nil)
                                   ))
```

it doesn't work. Than I tried:

```
(if (string= (buffer-name) "*ECB Symboldefinition*") (setq truncate-lines nil))
```

but it doesn't help also. Actually when I go to the `*ECB Symboldefinition*` buffer and do

```
(setq truncate-lines nil)
```

manually - it also works only for some time. So there must be a default value of a some variable.